# Help me with py2exe

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I made my program, and tested it in Command Prompt(by entering in the directory). Then I made a set up file, and put the setup file and my program in the same folder.

My setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['C:\Python26\test\testprogram.py'])
```

I went to run the setup program in command prompt(by entering in the directory and got the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Also this program contains several pictures and modules, could this be linked to that?

Answer (score 2):

The setup file is used to build / install files for distribution. you need to provide command to setup.py : "./setup.py command"
Go through, http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial and others on google search to understand it.

Py2Exe is an additional command to DistUtils, that creates standalone distributions for Win32.

so in your case it should be

```
setup.py py2exe
```

Look at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial